# camel test mockEndpoint patterns

Tags: apache-camel

I need some help regarding camel-test and mockEndpoint patterns.

When i return a pattern as "elasticsearch:*" then the elasticsearch endpoints are mocked

```
 public String isMockEndpointsAndSkip() {
        // override this method and return the pattern for which endpoints to mock.
        // use * to indicate all
        return "elasticsearch:*";
    }
```

But, when i return it as a list eg. "(direct:index|elasticsearch:*)" then the elasticsearch endpoints are **NOT** mocked.

```
 public String isMockEndpointsAndSkip() {
        // override this method and return the pattern for which endpoints to mock.
        // use * to indicate all
        return "(elasticsearch:*|direct:index)";
    }
```

Is anyone aware of such a behavior and knows how to work around this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got help over IRC.
apparently i forgot how regexp works.

it should be

```
return "(elasticsearch:.*|direct:index)";
```

a ".*" should be there, and not just a "*"